# Why are antibacterial body soaps uncommon?

Tags: bacteriology

If body odor is caused by bacteria, and antibacterial soap kills bacteria, why aren't antibacterial body soaps hailed as the holy grail of getting rid of body odor? I can only find hand soap that is antibacterial.

Comment: Please don't use antibacterial soaps.. Unless you're a nurse or a doctor. This isn't a highly scientific link or anything, but I appreciate [ASAP Science's](http://aplus.com/a/best-way-wash-hands?no_monetization=true) work that they do in scientific literacy.

Comment: I recommend watching the video in the link I posted. And please, there is very little scenarios where you should be using antibacterials or hand sanitizer

Comment: Oh, but *one* occasion you should *always* use hand sanitizer - when entering a hospital/clinic/doctors office

Comment: @Bob: I had the impression hand sanitizer is pretty different from "antibacterial" soaps.

Comment: @Bob okay, I won't do it, but still my question stands. Shouldn't antibacterial soap be able to get rid of body odor altogether?

Comment: @sumelic It is! Usually hand sanitizer consists of 60-70% ethanol. Which isn't really harmful, and doesn't contribute to bacterial resistance. However, I do not see how killing your microbiota is beneficial. Hand sanitizer seems unnecessary, unless it's use is a job-requirement.

Comment: @vrwim I don't think so. I would even argue that it would make body odor worse since you'd be killing all of the microbes on your body - even the microbes that act to inhibit the growth of body-odor-causing bacteria

Comment: I think there are some misconceptions here. One, the bacteria on your skin are part of you normal flora and contribute to your body odor. If you kill everything, you leave yourself at risk for opportunistic infection and even *worse* body odor as the composition of your flora changes. Two, alcohol hand sanitizer will not kill all the bacteria on your hand in the 5 seconds you rub it to evaporation. Alcohol is a denaturing agent and requires 30-60s wetted contact time actually kill anything substantial. Three, triclosan isn't effective anymore: people have been using it improperly for decades.